# Service in Arch not starting on PC boot

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, startup

I am running Arch Linux. I have a service on `/etc/systemd/system/` with the following description

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=(...)service.py
ExecReload=(...)service.py
Restart=always
```

I set it to start after the network is established as it depends on a network connection.

When I boot the PC, the service is always inactive. If I start it manually it runs perfectly. It also restarts if there is some internal error. Why does it not start on boot?

**EDIT**

When enabling the service I get this message:

```
➜  ~ systemctl enable py_service.service                                                                                                                     
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.`
```

Concerning these points:

1. it is not symlinked
2. it is not a helper
3. I thought this was covered by the `After=network...`
4. I do not know what this means

**EDIT 2** Following the suggestion of @dustball, I edited to:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/py_service.service 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=(...)service.py
ExecReload=(...)service.py
Restart=always
```

But it did not start on boot :(

**EDIT 3**
The above configuration works, I forgot to enable it (thanks to @Daniel H)
reload the services using

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then enable it using

```
systemctl enable py_service.service
```

Comment: Have you `enable`d the service? Also, this question might be better suited for [unix.se]

Comment: Have you considered adding a WantedBy, RequiredBy or some of the other suggested fields to the unit?

Comment: @Wieland I do not know what to add there as it is a contained service. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the journal, with `journalctl --unit <unit name>` for example?

Comment: the `journalctl` shows that if the service crashes it correctly restarts, but after boot there is no data, the service starting was done manually by me

Comment: After adding the `wanted-by` line, what happens when you try to enable it? You might also need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to get it to recognize changes to the unit file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error message already gives you the answer (partially). Services have an [Install] section. The only option in there is "WantedBy=". For a service to be enabled, it must be wanted by a target.

Example: NetworkManager has "WantedBy=network.target", so when you enable NetworkManager, it's grouped into network.target, and started as soon as systemd starts network.target

Think of it like the runlevels in SysV-init, a daemon must be inserted into a runlevel, otherwise... when should it start?

A safe default is to set "WantedBy=multi-user.target", it's the last one that's started.